# rails 4 sunspot with enum where conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, enums, sunspot

I have configured my model to be searchable by sunspot:

```
enum status: [ :draft, :unreviewed, :reviewed, :publish, :disable, :reject ]

searchable do
    text :name, :boost => 5
    text :description
    integer :status
    time :created_at
end
```

and in the controller:

```
@search = Product.search do
  fulltext params[:search]
  with :status, 3
  order_by :created_at, :desc
  paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10
end
```

this line `with :status, 3` used to be filter products with status `publish` which is I set using rails enum. But I got no results.

What did I miss? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small change in your your controller

```
@search = Product.search do
  fulltext params[:search]
  with(:status).equal_to(3)
  order_by :created_at, :desc
  paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10
end
```

and

> rake sunspot:reindex

to reindex your data

These are different type you can use with

```
with(:blog_id, 1)
with(:blog_id).equal_to(1)

with(:average_rating, 3.0..5.0)
with(:average_rating).between(3.0..5.0)

with(:category_ids, [1, 3, 5])
with(:category_ids).any_of([1, 3, 5])
```

Comment: The answer just uses a different syntax. This is a correct approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161105/how-do-i-scope-enums-in-rails-using-sunspot